# Processing loop and extracting data from java map

Tags: java, freemarker

I have template file that I try to make "dynamic" by using 'loop' command to generate table rows.

I also pass a HashMap to populate the data into the table, but I can't make it work.

This is the template:

```
<html>
 <p>
    <#list ['10', '20'] as sampleRate>
      <table>         
      <#list ['40'] as inputRange>
        <#list ['Off'] as dcFrequency>
          <#assign templateToken = inputRange + "_" + sampleRate + "_" + dcFrequency>
          <tr valign=top>
            <td>${templateToken}</td>
          </tr>
        </#list>
      </#list>
      </table>
    </#list>
</p>
<p><i>${.now?date}</i></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the java code:

```
tokens.put("40_10_Off", "WORKS!");
template.process(tokens, writer);
```

When running the 'process' it creates the table and put a

```
${40_10_Off}
```

but it doesn't pick the key from the java map...

How can I make the value of the variable I created be extracted from the Map I pass in the JAVA code?

Comment: Can you provide the errors your getting? Or at least specify `can't make it work`

Comment: sorry for that...I added what's go wrong.

Comment: no exceptions, it just creates the table but doesn't replace the string with the value from the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `${templateToken}` you simply tell FreeMarker to print the value of `templateToken`, which it does. If you put `tokens` into the data-model with some name, let's say "tookens":

```
tokens.put("40_10_Off", "WORKS!");
Map<String, Object> dataModel = new HashMap<>();
dataModel.put("tokens", tokens);
template.process(dataModel, writer);
```

then you can write `${tokens[templateToken]}` in the template. If you prefer using `tokens` as the data-model itself (as in your original example), then you can write:

```
${.vars[templateToken]}
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer! unfortunately, something not working for me. even if I just try to print ${tokens} it doesn't work: exception=
FreeMarker template error:
For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this has evaluated to an extended_hash (HashMap wrapped into f.t.DefaultMapAdapter):

Comment: I'm running the exactly java snippet you suggested. perhaps it can't evaluate the "templateToken" which <#assign templateToken ... >

Comment: By the way, i"m not sure it adds something creating the map "tokens" inside the "dataModel" map

Comment: As the error message says, `tokens` is there, but you can't print it as is, since it's not a string or number or date. What's the error message when you write `tokens[templateToken]`? Maybe the key stored in `templateToken` is not accurate?

Comment: If `#assign` has a problem, the template processing stops with error. So the assignment itself is successful.

Comment: There's no value in adding `tokens` if you will not ever need to add other non-token variables. So feel free to use `.vars`.

Comment: Is it even possible to access the map with an #assign variable or perhaps it can be accessed only by a static string?!?

Comment: Finally got it to work using ${.vars[templateToken]}   :-)
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score -1):

You first need to know the value you want to replace (e.g.: "40_10_Off", or anything between **{}**), let's name this "ToBeReplacedToken" and then replace it using:

```
String.replace("ToBeReplacedToken",tokens.get("ToBeReplacedToken"));
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example for this please - I appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you were talking about freemarker, I just looked into the tags, I think @ddekany's answer might be more useful to you.